# Changing from Ultegra 6800 crank to r8000 dual power meter

Tags: power

I currently have a shimano ultegra 6800 crank set on my 2014 trek speed concept 7.0. I want to install a dual side power meter and can only find the r8000 dual side power meter setup. Will the r8000 work on the bike I’m riding?

Comment: If we take the power meter aspect out of the equation, I would like to replace my 6800 FC 52/36 and 6800 FD with the R8000 FD and FC 52/36. I'd like to utilize my existing 6800 brifters. Am I correct, based upon the prior posts that the cable pull on the brifters (6800 vs 8000) are identical and that the 0.4 mm difference in chainring spread is dealt with by way of the 8000 FD, and not the cable pull from the brifter?

Comment: @bryce - this question is almost 2 years old now.  How did you get on with your change?  Do feel free to add your own answer to this question sharing your progress and results.

Answer (score 4):

This FC-6800 and the FC-R8000 are parts based on the same design standard, Shimano Hollowtech II. Here you can find all the compatible pieces : https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/technologies/component/details/hollowtech-2.html - So it will be compatible.

The only issue you can have if is your new powermeter have an external part on the arm crank, like the battery of the Stages powermeter. This part can interfere with you bike frame. So be sure you have enough space between the crank arm and your frame. This dimension is not part of the Hollowtech II design standard.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, with respect, both above answers **may** be wrong. The inner chainring on the R8000 is [about 0.4mm inboard](https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=149719) of the chainring on the 6800 crankset. While [the Shimano compatibility diagram](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.7?acid=C-455&cid=C-453) is a bit hard to read, it says that **technically**, current generation (including R8k) front derailleurs can shift current or previous (including 6800) cranksets, but the previous generation FDs are not officially compatible with the new cranksets. To clarify: the issue is that with an R8k crankset, the 6800 FD may not move inwards enough to properly downshift and/or you could get some additional chainrub from the FD position. Shimano made the change to improve the chainline on bikes with longer chainstays and/or disc hubs.

That said, 0.4mm difference is not a lot, and that could be within the limits of adjustment. It would naturally be in Shimano's interest to sell you more stuff, so of course they'd say the parts aren't compatible, right? You may wish to Google this issue more. Some comments [here](https://cyclingtips.com/2018/09/shimano-ultegra-r8000-mechanical-groupset-long-term-review/) say that there is no practical issue in mixing the relevant 6800 parts in. (Not clear if they've tried it or they just think so, and which parts they've mixed.)

In the worst case, front derailleurs aren't that expensive, and the new FD is definitely a significant improvement (easier to set up and adjust) than the old one, plus the new FDs are officially compatible with the old shifters (as shown on Shimano's chart).

The original question didn't ask, but there's a larger issue: drive-side Shimano power meters are [likely to be inaccurate](https://gplama.com/2019/06/29/shimano-crankset-power-meters/). This is due to the asymmetric and complex design of the drive-side crankarm. At a steady 250W, the guy in the link estimates that the drive side PMs read about 7.9% lower than a comparison pedal power meter. The issue doesn't appear to be something manufacturers could easily correct in software (from a conversation with [an engineer on a different forum](https://forums.thepaceline.net/showpost.php?p=2561022&postcount=8)), and in any case, many manufacturers haven't acknowledged it. I believe the guy in the link said that the non-drive power meters should be accurate. I also think he said that previous generation power meters should be more accurate than current generation ones, but there is still some inaccuracy there as they are slightly asymmetric.

This may not seriously affect your training. However, it is a genuine issue, even though it doesn't appear to be widely known. If you must go dual sided, I wouldn't rely too much on the left-right balance metrics you get, and you may want to keep in mind that your measured total power is a bit low.

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone can link to this 0.4mm change in Shimano documentation. The link points to something someone said in a forum. I have 8000 cranks with 6800 FD and get some minimal chain rub on the FD in the small ring. I have the opportunity to get a 8000 FD and move the 6800 to another bike but want to make sure this isn't just speculation. Shimano docs do say the same chainline for both 6800 and 8000

Comment: @Andrew this is a good point. Shimano's technical documents do not say this. In theory, I think that moving the chainrings should have affected the chainline, but all generations are listed as having a 43.5mm chainline. Nonetheless, many groupset reviews do state that the inner chainring position is different on the R9100/8k/7k generation. For example: https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/components/groupsets/groupset-road/shimano-dura-ace-r9100-review/ https://www.cyclingnews.com/news/shimano-dura-ace-r9100-first-ride-review/

Comment: I have both cranks and measured the distance between the big ring and inner ring with a pocket ruler. Looks to me like the distance is about 6mm for 6800 and 5.5mm for 8000. So the inner ring on the 8000 is actually about further .5mm away from the frame than on the 6800, not inboard like was speculated. This is assuming too that the chainline on the big ring is the same for both and documentation says 43.5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, FC-6800 and FC-R8000 cranksets are completely compatible (except for chainring to arm interface). You did not specify what your current powermeter/head unit are, but I'd check compatibility with whatever's on R8000 just in case.