# Swapping parts from old bike to new frameset

Tags: road-bike, frames, parts, specialized-bikes, new-bicycle-assembly

I have a Piave (around 2009-ish year) road bike with a frame that has become to small for me. It has pretty good components i.e Shimano Ultegra and threadless stem etc. There is a 2014 S-Works Venge frameset being sold and I was wondering, could I swap all my components (bar the fork, seatpost, BB, headset) Onto this new frame if I needed to? I have looked around to try find the sizes of things to make sure they fit but haven't found a lot. Any help?

Comment: You should find a list of specs for each frame and see which ones are the same.  Consider selling off the old bike as-is and price up a new bike vs new components.

Comment: Can you confirm what you mean by “threaded stem”? Usually that means quill stem to me, and those are vintage items. Latest you would have seen them as standard equipment might have been 1990 or so.

Comment: Probably a bit later, most riders appear to have quill stems in the cyclocross worlds 1991, although the TV is quite blurry.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Are you sure about the 1990 date? From what I've read, that's when the Aheadset was being developed, and adoption stretched over the next decade. (The OP's 2009 date is well within the threadless era, in any case.)

Comment: @RLH no, I’m not sure. It was a ballpark guess. Also, I might have meant the late 1990s or early 2000s as the time frame when most new bikes came with threadless stems.

Comment: @WeiwenNg this page is rapidly becoming the top Google hit for Piave! reading here http://www.vorb.org.nz/piave-roadbikes-does-anyone-know-anything-about-piave-roadbi-t68433.html shows it's a bit of a dead end online. I've adapted my answer to include a link to the terminology index for headsets, and if OP has any doubt, can update us to your query, or add new specific questions separately

Comment: I realize this is getting off-topic, but the transition to threadless mostly happened in late 90s/early 2000s. As an example, by 2000 Cannondale had switched all of their MTBs to threadless, but their lower end road racing bikes up to the R600 (9 spd 105 components, probably about USD1000 retail price) were still quills.

Comment: Sorry I meant threadless! The normal standard on all good road/mtb bikes. This bike has good components i.e old ultegra

Answer (score 6):

Breaking it down:

- Wheels, yes, if they are rim brake wheels onto a rim brake frame
- Rear derailleur, yes
- Chain, yes
- Cranks, yes
- Front derailleur, yes if yours is a braze-on type, otherwise new one needed
- Brake calipers, yes (looking at the frame brake mounts [here](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk/product/10957/2014-s-works-venge-frameset/))
- Shifters, yes
- Saddle, yes

All of these parts have pretty standardised interfaces with the bike, which would explain why you haven't found much information.

Rim brake wheels have a 130mm spacing at the rear, while disc brake wheels are wider in the frame, or newer ones have thru-axles etc which are different again. If both frames are rim brakes then all is well.

You've correctly identified that bottom bracket, seat post and headset are most likely not compatible, as these components are a bridge between the specifics of the frame and the parts which get attached to it. The [2014 Venge](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk/product/10957/2014-s-works-venge-frameset/) has a [narrow OSBB](https://www.kogel.cc/blogs/kbba/specialized-osbb-explained) bottom bracket, an aero profile seat post and headset with 1-1/8" upper and 1-3/8" lower bearings.

You may need new handlebars and stem if these are not included with the Venge frameset, depending on the compatibility of your current set, or if you want a more integrated, aero style set to compliment the Venge frame. See our headset [explainer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/10078#10078) if applicable.

Answer (score 3):

A few other considerations when considering moving components from an older bike to a new frame.

An Ultegra groupset in 2009 would be a 6700 or possibly 6600 series 10 speed.That's sort-of not doing the Venge frame justice. Would you be happier buying a used complete bike with a lesser frame but a newer 11 speed 105 or Ultegra groupset?

The Venge will have fairly aggressive cockpit geometry. Low stack and long reach. Is this what you want? The 2014 Venge geometry can be found [here](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk/product/10957/2014-s-works-venge-frameset/) (credit to Swifty for finding this). Compare the stack and reach with your current bike.

Beware that the headset and bottom bracket bearings on the Venge may be worn out, finding replacements might be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

A minor point of information on the cranks: you presumably have cranks with a 24mm spindle. The 2014 Venge could have a BB that takes a 30mm spindle. As detailed in [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/67461/38270), BBs for any shell type might take 30mm spindle cranks or 24mm spindle cranks (or, less commonly, other spindle diameters like 25mm Campagnolo spindles, 24/22mm SRAM GXP spindles, 29.something mm SRAM DUB spindles, etc).

If the stock BB is designed for a 30mm spindle, you'll need adapters to accept the 24mm spindle. There's a link to one by Wheels Manufacturing in the post I linked to. In theory, you could also replace the bearings to ones that are designed for the Specialized BB shell and that accommodate only 24mm spindles, but I wouldn't bother with this. You could also get a crankset with a 30mm spindle. In theory, the spindle could be either slightly stiffer or slightly lighter than your existing one. However, wouldn't bother with this either.

Many current aerodynamic framesets come with proprietary integrated stems and handlebars. These shield the cables from the air. Some may laugh at this, and these are definitely harder to work on, but this does in fact make a measurable improvement in aerodyamics. I am not certain that the 2014 Venge takes a proprietary stem. [This 2017 review](https://cyclingtips.com/2017/01/specialized-venge-vias-expert-disc-ultegra-review-aero-disc-and-all-business/) of the disc brake Venge appears to show a standard stem. If so, you'll be able to swap your current parts in without penalty.

While you didn't ask, I would add that if you are looking to improve aerodynamics, your kit and your helmet are two major areas where improvements are a lot cheaper than a new frameset. Moreover, while latex tubes do need to be pumped up every day, they are a substantial and very cheap improvement in rolling resistance. This is not to stop you from getting that Venge if you want it. However, if the only reason you're getting it is to improve your aerodynamics, then you should be aware that there are most cost-effective alternatives.

Comment: The Spesh [website](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk/product/10957/2014-s-works-venge-frameset/) says its an OS bb, and there seems to be an explainer on [kogel.cc](https://www.kogel.cc/blogs/kbba/specialized-osbb-explained) to say it is a slightly narrower 61mm bb on the 2014 SWorks, as in narrower than 68x42 BB30